# From where the value is copied when we process undo(`ctrl+z`)?

Tags: vb.net, windows, clipboard, undo

I have a doubt, from where the value is copied when we process undo(`ctrl+z`)? where the value is temporarily holding? it is not in the `clipboard` is their anything like `clipboard` or `buffer`?

for a text box i can set 100 step back `undo operation` by using a stack. Following is the code for this implementation in vb.net:

```
    Dim undoStack(100) As String ' stack array
    Dim stackTop As Integer = 0 ' stack counter
    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
        If stackTop < 100 Then ' 100 step back undoStack
            ' system will perform the operation when use ctrl+z for undoStack
            ' so i choose f1 key for undoStack to check the code
            If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 And stackTop > 0 Then ' check whether the key is F1 and stack is empty or not
                TextBox1.Text = undoStack(stackTop - 1) 'load lst change to the text box from stack
                undoStack(stackTop) = Nothing ' clear the stack top value
                stackTop -= 1 ' decrement the stack top by 1
            ElseIf TextBox1.Text <> undoStack(stackTop) Then
                undoStack(stackTop) = TextBox1.Text ' push value to stackTop
                stackTop += 1 'Increment the stackTop
            End If
        Else
            ' call function to perform left shift
            ' insert change in last position
        End If
    End Sub
```

Hope that in system their must be such a mechanism for this purpose. **May i know**

- What is the name of `buffer/stack` that windows used for `undo Operation`
- Is it accessible through `vb.net` code like `clipboard`

Notes: The code is not complete but it functions as i wish.

Comment: nope - you want UNDO you have to implement it yourself - think about it - where should the system get the changing state from? Make copies of your processes memory? Think how much space you would need for this - and where should the system know when it has to take a snapshot?

Comment: In an "undo buffer", stored in memory in whatever code implements the command.  Such a buffer usually only stores the difference between current and previous text to keep memory usage low.  The Edit and Richtext controls have a very simple implementation, just one level deep.  Programmer editors are much fancier with multiple levels.  A strict implementation detail.

Comment: Does these temporary memory is accessible like clipboard?

Comment: @Sample it's an implementation detail! - so no - it won't be in general

Comment: @   Carsten König: i don't want to implement just want to know how it is achieved and where it is stored.

Comment: This does not ask a programming question.

Comment: I think this is actually a very interesting question and I also didn't know that you have to create a buffer yourself. Someone should give a proper answer and let others know how it's done, etc.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss Though interesting, it's still to *too broad*. Buffer or no buffer: It's entirely up to you how you implement such a functionality as long as the data can revert to previous state.